# BPF in python to sniff packets for multiple TCP ports

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, bpf

I got code from http://allanrbo.blogspot.in/2011/12/raw-sockets-with-bpf-in-python.html. It works fine, but I want to sniff the traffic on multiple TCP ports like port `9000`, `80`, `22`...

So I have modified the `filter_list` like blow

```
filters_list = [  
    # Must have dst port 67. Load (BPF_LD) a half word value (BPF_H) in   
    # ethernet frame at absolute byte offset 36 (BPF_ABS). If value is equal to  
    # 67 then do not jump, else jump 5 statements.  
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 36),  
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 0, 5), <===== Here I added another port
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 80, 0, 5),


    # Must be UDP (check protocol field at byte offset 23)  
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_B | BPF_ABS, 23),   
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 0x06, 0, 3), #<==Changed for TCP "0x06"

    # Must be IPv4 (check ethertype field at byte offset 12)  
    bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 12),   
    bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 0x0800, 0, 1),  

    bpf_stmt(BPF_RET | BPF_K, 0x0fffffff), # pass  
    bpf_stmt(BPF_RET | BPF_K, 0), # reject   ]
```

The thing is, sometimes it is working sometimes it is not, like getting traffic only on 9000 but not 80, sometimes getting traffic on 80. I didnt understood the code completely. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem seems to come from the logic of your first two conditional jumps. Specifically:

```
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 0, 5), # if false, skip 5 instructions
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 80, 0, 5),
```

An instruction `bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, <val>, <jtrue>, <jfalse>)` means

```
if value currently in register K is equal to <val>
    then add <jtrue> to instruction pointer
        (i.e. skip the next <jtrue> instructions),
    else add <jfalse> instead`
```

So the two lines mean:

```
if port is 9000
    then if port is 80
        then go on with checks…
    else skip 5 instructions (i.e. reject)
else
    skip 5 instructions (i.e. pass, as jump offset was not updated from 5 to 6)
```

While you probably want something that looks more like:

```
if port is 9000
    then go on with checks…
else
    if port is 80
        then go on with checks…
    else reject
```

I have not tested, but to get this logics I would say you need to adapt the jump offsets as follows:

```
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 1, 0), # if true skip 1 insn
                                                 # (i.e. port 80 check) else 0
                                                 # and check for port 80
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 80, 0, 5),   # if true skip 0 else skip 5
                                                 # (and land on “reject”)
```

**Edit 1:** And then for filtering three ports, that would become:

```
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 8084, 2, 0), # skip the next 2 checks if true
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 1, 0), # skip the next check if true
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 22,   0, 5), # if true go on else reject
```

**Edit 2:** To also filter on source port (in addition to destination port), you could try something like this (still not tested on my side):

```
# Load TCP src port into register K, and check port value
# For packets with IP header len == 20 bytes, TCP src port should be at offset 34
# We adapt the jump offsets to go to next check if no match (or to “reject” after
# the last check), or to skip all remaining checks on ports if a match is found.
bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 34),           # 34 == offset of src port
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 8084, 6, 0),
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 5, 0),
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 22,   4, 0),

# As before: if no match on src port, check on dst port
bpf_stmt(BPF_LD | BPF_H | BPF_ABS, 36),
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 8084, 2, 0),
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 1, 0),
bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 22,   0, 5),

…
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to filter 2 or more ports, what is the filter. I tried 3 ports---> `bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 8084, 1, 0), bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 9000, 1, 0),bpf_jump(BPF_JMP | BPF_JEQ | BPF_K, 22, 0, 5),`. Im getting only traffic for `9000` and `22`.

Comment: @Veerendra: I edited my answer for three ports (still not tested, though).

Comment: Thanks you! You saved my day :) Right now im getting the packet which destination port==`9000` or `8084` or `22`(Whatever we added in the filter), but I want two ways, like I need packet which has interested ports(The interested port can be in `source` or `destination`: need both packets!) Any help?

Comment: Awesome! it is working!. Just curious, if I want to filer `IP`s, how can I achieve it?

Comment: @Veerendra For IP it would be just the same: load data at the correct offset (should be 26 for IPv4 src, 30 for IPv4 dst) but load them as words (`BPF_W` instead of `BPF_H`), check the value and jump to relevant instructions. That should be rather simple to do with the existing filters as starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I know you want to attach a filter to your raw socket, it's what I recently work with. Thanks to more than weeks of hard work, I got an easy way to attach a filter to a raw socket. I would like to share with yours :)
First make sure you already install `tcpdump` (It's a Linux system manager tools), if your platform is one of distribution in Linux, let's go to next step.
Second you need to have a `sudo or root` permission to execute the tool.
Third follow demo example, change it to suit your situation.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i enp4s0 -dd 'tcp and (port 9000 or port 80 or port 22)'
```

Let me explain the parameter first.
`tcpdump` --> Dump traffic on a network
`-i`      --> Specific the interface
`enp4s0`  --> Network Interface
`-dd`  -->  Dump packet-matching code as a C program fragment.
`tcp and (port 9000 or port 80 or port 22)` --> Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) syntax

After this command you should generate some code same like this:

```
{ 0x28, 0, 0, 0x0000000c },
{ 0x15, 0, 8, 0x000086dd },
{ 0x30, 0, 0, 0x00000014 },
{ 0x15, 0, 21, 0x00000006 },
{ 0x28, 0, 0, 0x00000036 },
....
```

It looks like a mess, but don't worry, let's go on with brave.

First let me clear what it's, this is a the packet filter code, if you already learn assembly language before, you will feel familiar with it.

Second because it's C stylish code, it doesn't fit our python usage, so we need to polish the data, use follow python code

```py
import subprocess

cmd = "sudo tcpdump -i enp4s0 -dd 'tcp and (port 9000 or port 80 or port 22)'"
tcpdumpBinary = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
macroString = '( ' + tcpdumpBinary.decode('utf-8').replace(
            '\n', '').replace('{', '[').replace('}', ']') + ')'
macroString = eval(macroString)
```

Third now you can use the `macroString` same like the `filters_list`.

This method help me get rid of the filter code dilemma, I hope it will be helpful to you.